# POST without line feed fails, but with line feed works?

Tags: php, json, post

I'm debugging a PHP application where I have to POST some data to my server, and then parse it and return some values -- super simple stuff.

The data is in the format:

```
action=display_all_pols&donate_form=1&user_state=&state=AK&pols[LA][0][post_id]=2714&pols[LA][0][first_name]=Ralph&pols[LA][0][last_name]=Abraham &pols[LA][0][profile_image]=2762
```

My data size varies from something small, e.g. 187 bytes, to something larger, e.g. 46KB.

I noticed my application was failing to parse the POST correctly. The code is something like this:

```
function Foo() {
    $state = somehow_get_state();
    $bar = $_POST['pols'][$state];
    // cool logic and stuff
```

I immediately put a `die(var_dump($_POST));` inside `Foo()`, and noticed that only a portion of the data was actually being POSTed.

When I tested this on the command line, I noticed a difference between:

```
POST http://10.1.10.22/wesupportthat/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
action=display_all_pols&donate_form=1&user_state=&state=AK&pols[LA][0][post_id]=2714&pols[LA][0][first_name]=Ralph&pols[LA][0][last_name]=Abraham &pols[LA][0][profile_image]=2762
```

And this (notice the line feeds);

```
POST http://10.1.10.22/wesupportthat/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
action=display_all_pols&donate_form=1&user_state=&state=AK&
pols[LA][0][post_id]=2714&
pols[LA][0][first_name]=Ralph&
pols[LA][0][last_name]=Abraham&
pols[LA][0][profile_image]=2762
```

The former would only POST roughly 3.1KB of the data, while the later POSTs the entire thing.

Is there a reason why? I'm posting valid JSON, and for the love of me can't figure out why one works and the other doesn't.

In order to create the JSON, I'm creating a nested array, like this:

```
array( // root-level array
    array(
        '1' => 'somestring',
        '2' => '...',
        '3' => '...',
        '4' => '...'
    ),
    array( // same as previous),
    // more arrays, potentially up to 50 total
)
```

and then calling `json_encode($my_array, JSON_HEX_APOS);` to create the JSON.

I'm hoping this is just a rubber duck moment. :-)

Edit: I'm stepping away from my computer, but the TCP captures show the same thing. Will also add my Apache/php info when I get back.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with json, so this may be of no help, but two things come to mind: 1: you have a badly encoded character in the string, which is breaking it, or 2 would a space in the string cause it to fail? `[last_name]=Abraham &pols` Notice the space after Abraham...

Comment: You could try `utf8_encode()` over the array before you encode it as JSON.

Comment: Would be helpful to know what portion of the data is parsing and which isn't in relation to your query string.

Comment: @EternalHour the first 3.1KB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using suhosin extension, and you see lines like this after your failed trials in /var/log/user.log:

```
suhosin[...]: ALERT - configured POST variable limit exceeded - dropped variable 'x' (attacker 'x.y.z.207', file 'some_script.php')
```

Then it's probably this extension which is messing your requests. you need in this case to disable or update suhosin's configuration, for example in /etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini

Updating or adding these lines :

```
suhosin.post.max_vars = 3000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 3000
```

This configuration allows at most 3000 variables coming in a request.